# Change more complex css with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I have this CSS code:

```
        #texte>div:not(:last-child)>p:not(.show){
        display:none;
    }
```

And I need to write javascript in order to change the style to match the above css. I honestly have no idea how to get to this kind of selectors using js.

Comment: JavaScript can only change styles on specific elements. The best you could do is generate CSS via javascript and add it to the head (as if it was a standard `<style>` tag), or select the elements manually (jQuery and similar libraries support selecting using CSS syntax)

Comment: Also you may want to consider simplifying your structure. Unless all the divs really are representing the same sort of data, you should probably add a class to the last one instead of selecting it like that.

Comment: It might be more efficient to modify the classes attached to the parent class (eg `#texte ... { display: none }; #texte.open ... { display: block }`).  Also `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: The structure is that complex and I can do nothing about it.
In simple terms, `#texte` is a table div and its divs are table-cells. I got too much text in some of the cells (all except the last) so I hide it and put a "more.." button.
The `show` class are the `p` elements containing the text that will still be displayed before clicking the "more" button.
Obviously, at some point, the text should restore the attributes above, so that's where I need help

Comment: In that case, I would assign a `snip` (or similar) class to all the divs which should be reduced, and remove this class via JavaScript when the show button is pressed. No need to change styles via JavaScript at all.

Comment: `#texte>.snip>p{display:none}` is all you would need (in fact, `.snip>p{display:none}` would be enough)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#texte>div:not(:last-child)>p:not(.show)");
for(var i=0; el=elemenets[i]; i++) {
   el.setAttribute("style", "...your styles here...");
}
```